# Combining read and write file I/O classes

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex, fstream

In a project of mine, I created classes that handles file I/O. I have a FileReader and a FileWriter. The FileReader can read data from a file, the FileWriter can write data to a file. A new class is introduced in my project that needs the ability to read and write in the same file. For this class I need to combine the FileReader and the FileWriter class.

```
#include "Read.h"
#include "Write.h"

class ReadWrite : public Read, public Write
{

};
```

With this approach reading and writing can be done at the same time. As far as I know you cannot read and write at the same time. The only solution that I have is creating a proxy class:

```
#include "Read.h"
#include "Write.h"

#include <mutex>

class ReadWrite : private Read, private Write
{
private:
    std::mutex lock;

public:

    int readData() {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> guard(lock);
        return readX();
    }

    void writeData(int x) {
        std::lock_guard<mutex> guard(lock);
        writeX(x);
    }
};
```

Are there other solutions to solve this problem? The problem with this solution is that readX and writeX do not need to be fully synchronized. How can I design a file I/O system that has a separate read, write and readwrite class without having much synchronization overhead.

Comment: Could you provide a decent code sample of what you have. It's a bit unclear and also may depend on your primary use case, what's the best way to do it.

Comment: Also is there any particular reason you're reinventing ``iostream``? If you're after thread safety, wouldn't it be much simpler to simply lock access to the `iostream` rather than trying to make individually thread-safe read and write operations?

Comment: You also can use `shared_lock` if you foresee multiple reads at same time.

Comment: I miss some features in fstream that I need and I do not want to keep track of files that are not closed.

Comment: When Read and Write has a base class with public methods, then a call to the public method will become ambiguous. The compiler does not know which base class method you want to call.